# Pearson multiple correlation with Scipy

Tags: python, scipy, pearson-correlation

I am trying to do something quite simple compute a Pearson correlation matrix of several variables that are given as columns of a DataFrame. I want it to ignore nans and provide also the p-values. `scipy.stats.pearsonr` is insufficient because it works only for two variables and cannot account for nans. There should be something better than that...

For example,

```
    df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[6,5,4],[1,None,9]])

       0    1  2
    0  1  2.0  3
    1  6  5.0  4
    2  1  NaN  9
```

The columns of df are the variables and the rows are observations. I would like a command that returns a 3x3 correlation matrix, along with a 3x3 matrix of corresponding p-values. I want it to omit the None. That is, the  correlation between [1,6,1],[2,5,NaN] should be the correlation between [1,6] and [2,5].

There must be a nice Pythonic way to do that, can anyone please suggest?

Comment: What is the pearson correlation between these two vectors: [6,5,4],[1,None,9]?

Comment: Thanks @cel. I want variables to be columns and observations to be rows. So to answer your question, the correlation between [1,6,1],[2,5,NaN] should be the correlation between [1,6] and [2,5]. I edited the questions as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have your data in a pandas DataFrame, you can simply use `df.corr()`.

From the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.corr.html):

> `DataFrame.corr(method='pearson', min_periods=1)`
>   Compute pairwise correlation of columns, excluding NA/null values